# How to compose multiple authentication handlers in Katana?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

I want to create a web API service which exposes a resource that can be accessed using either a client certificate **OR** a JWT token for authentication.

I found some middleware that [validates a client certificate](http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/11/client-certificate-authentication-middleware-for-katana/) and some nice instructions how to [create your own authentication middleware](https://coding.abel.nu/2014/06/writing-an-owin-authentication-middleware/). Microsoft has middleware [`OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthbearerauthenticationmiddleware(v=vs.113).aspx) that validates JWT tokens. Obviously I can't just install them both as the first middleware will terminate the pipeline when authentication fails.

So I thought I would create a composite authentication middleware class that owns two [`AuthenticationHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.infrastructure.authenticationhandler(v=vs.113).aspx) objects and would call `AuthenticateAsync()` for the handlers from its `AuthenticateCoreAsync()` until one returns a valid `AuthenticationTicket`. The problem is that the `CreateHandler` methods in the `AuthenticationMiddleware` class are protected, so I can't seem to compose these objects.

I cannot instantiate the `OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler` class myself as it is internal.

How can I re-use these existing middleware components to enable both types of authentication without copying the code into my own handler?

Or am I going about this the wrong way and is there another way of having two authentication methods on the same web API service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually not true that authentication middleware terminates the pipeline when authentication fails. It is designed to be composable.

Every middleware can contribute zero or one identity which becomes a `ClaimsPrincipal` in the end.

Comment: Oh, I did not realize that. Let me try that out. Thanks!